# Solr 4.10.0 copyField does not work

Tags: solr, schema, solr4

I use dataimport to manage the following schema:

```
<field name="PageID" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" /> 

   <field name="Content" type="text_ar" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" termVectors="true" />
   <field name="PageNum" type="int" indexed="false" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />
   <field name="Part" type="int" indexed="false" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />

   <field name="BookID" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
   <field name="BookTitle" type="text_ar" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
   <field name="BookInfo" type="text_ar" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
   <field name="BookCat" type="int" indexed="false" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />

   <field name="TitleText" type="text_ar" indexed="false" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="true" />
   <field name="TitleID" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="true" />
   <field name="TitleSub" type="int" indexed="false" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="true" />
   <field name="TitleLevel" type="int" indexed="false" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="true" />
```

Till this point, everything is going fine, as I think, and search has been performed very well on the `Content` field. However, I decided to make a pool for search, to allow searching among `Content`, `BookTitle` and `TitleText` in one query by adding new field named `SearchPool` and then copying those fields to it. So I just added the following lines to the schema:

```
<field name="SearchPool" type="text_ar" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" termVectors="true" />

   <copyField source="Content" dest="SearchPool" />
   <copyField source="BookTitle" dest="SearchPool" />
   <copyField source="TitleText" dest="SearchPool" />
```

Then I repeated the dataimport , from the database, then I restarted the TomCat. Now, I could not able to get any results by:

```
select?q=SearchPool%3Aالصلاة&wt=json&indent=true
```

While Searching among `Content` returns results! In addition, `SearchPool` does not appear as a field in the result returned by `Content`.

Comment: You should find an error in your logs when performing the index operation. TitleText has `multivalued="true"` whereas SearchPool has `multiValued="false"`.

Comment: @cheffe Yes it is, I fixed it and SearchPool multiValued has been set to `true` then I re-imported the data again and it works fine. Thank you. However, the default search field has been stated as depreciated and it does not work. i.e searching query without defining a search field, will return no results.

Comment: I am not too informed about that depreciation, but as most guys I know use dismax/edismax and these queryhandlers have their own configuration option for a set of default fields, I assume that this is the reason. The trend goes to dismax/edismax and their capability of crossfield-searches, those catchall fields are not state of the art anymore.